# OpenGL Not Drawing To SDL2 Window

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, sdl

So I am working on making a game in c++ and I am using SDL2 and OpenGL/GLEW. I am attempting to just draw basic shapes to my window, however, it is just creating a black screen when it should be drawing a triangle. This is the code.

Game Loop:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Window window("Test", 600, 400);
    RenderingEngine e(window);

    e.Init();

    while (!window.IsCloseRequested()) {
        window.SwapBuffers();
        e.Render();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Window Class:

```
Window::Window(const std::string& title, unsigned int width, unsigned int height) :
    m_title(title), m_width(width), m_height(height), m_isCloseRequested(false) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(m_window, m_glContext);

    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    GLenum res = glewInit();

    if (res != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Error initializting OpenGL." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void Window::SwapBuffers() {
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);
}
```

RenderingEngine Class:

```
RenderingEngine::RenderingEngine(const Window& window) : m_window(&window) {

}

RenderingEngine::~RenderingEngine() {
    if (m_window) delete m_window;
}

void RenderingEngine::Init() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);
}

void RenderingEngine::Render() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}
```

I cannot figure out why it isn't drawing to the screen, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're setting up back face culling specifying that your front facing triangles have clockwise winding order, and you want to cull everything that is not front facing:

```
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

But the triangle you specify has counter-clockwise winding order:

```
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

You can verify that by drawing the points on a piece of paper, with the x-axis going right and the y-axis up. You will see the order of points is counter-clockwise around the origin.

Based on this, your triangle is eliminated by back face culling. Since using counter-clockwise winding order is much more commonly used with OpenGL, I would suggest using it by changing the `glFrontFace()` call to:

```
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
```

Or don't make the call at all, since this is the default.

Comment: I changed the culling to a counter clockwise order and arranged my vertices correctly, however, it is still just a black screen when its drawn.

Comment: No need to change the vertices, they were already counter-clockwise.

Comment: The vertices are in the correct, counter-clockwise order, but the screen is still just black.

Answer (score 0):

you didn`t loaded View/Projection/Model matrices ... i guess that would be a problem... also you should use shaders if you want to make in 3.2 style